# Why does the unanswered questions tab *not* show questions which have answers?

Tags: support, bug, unanswered-questions

It is common knowledge that a question only becomes "answered" when it has [an answer with a score of at least +1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers/18871).

Why, then, do all of the questions in the unanswered queue have no answers (or at least, on the first few pages have no answers)?

A specific example: I have a technically unanswered question, but it has an answer (currently on -1). This question no longer appears (EDIT: *where it should appear*) in any of the lists of unanswered questions which I can find.

EDIT: I have added the (bug) tag as I think this is a bug - the software counts a question with an answer with non-positive score as unanswered, but in a second tier. If you sort the unanswered questions by votes then questions without an answer come before those with an answer, even if that answer is very negative. Which is annoying!

Comment: Could you be be more specific about what you mean by *unanswered queue*. (Which list were you checking.) Was it [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)?

Comment: Perhaps you're in the ["no answers" tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)?

Comment: FWIW if you meant [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64492/automorphisms-inducing-automorphisms-of-quotient-groups), I found it on [page 661](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=661&tab=newest) when unanswered questions are sorted by *newest*. (I do not know whether unanswered questions can be sorted by recent activity.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak They were the two I could find, along with sorting specific tags by "unanswered" [(for example)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory). I can find no pseudo-answered questions in these lists.

Comment: IIRC, in the ["sort by unanswered" tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=695&sort=unanswered), the questions that have answers are listed *after* those that do have answers.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah, okay, I understand the problem with the unaswered queue now (but not for sorting by unanswered - but perhaps that is just a problem with the same word having different definitions). It seems that I was sorting by "no answers". Which is the default (which defies the definitions....but anyway...)

Comment: What I have learned: SE calls a question "unanswered" if it has no proper answer. However, those which have an answer, no matter how bad, are still harder to find. So there is a two-tier system, which is annoying.

Comment: After Lord_Farin's comment I have found this question both [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory?page=16&sort=unanswered&pagesize=50) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/group-theory?page=18&tab=newest). Since the first list is ordered by upvotes, I expected it to be on the first page. I did not know that unanswered questions having answers are at the end of this list.