# What is the community user doing?

Tags: discussion, community-user

The community user has been making some odd edits. I was wondering if anyone knows why? (I presume *someone* does!) The edits claim that they are "(Migrating) MSO links to MSE links". The links are changed, but so has the coding...

For example, in [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11815/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-not-show-questions-which-have-answers) of mine it has added in `<p>...</p>` for new paragraphs, it has replaced `*...*` with `<em>...</em>` to italicise words, and it has replaced a "referenced" link with an inline one, that is,

> Writing...I want to give a `[link][2]` then some more writing...
>
> `[2]: http://target-url`

is replaced with

> Writing...I want to give a `<a href="http://target-url">link</a>` then some more writing...

I find these edits odd because they are replacing what I presumed were the "proper" StackExchange coding with the more common stuff. I presume that these are the "proper" conventions because it is what you get if you click on the buttons above the box where you write or edit posts.

Comment: It seems that the community bot has already corrected back to the [previous version of your post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/11815/revisions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Should we unbugger the changes Community has just made, or will they be automatically fixed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230292/should-we-unbugger-the-changes-community-has-just-made-or-will-they-be-automati) at meta.stackexchange. (And other questions linked there.)

In short, recently meta.stackoverflow was split into http://meta.stackoverflow.com (which will serve as a meta for SO) and http://meta.stackexchange.com (which will serve as meta for the whole network). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mso-mse-split/info) for some links containing more information about the split.

The community bot seems to be editing posts containing links in the form`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/question/XXXXXX` and replacing them by `https://meta.stackexchange.com/question/XXXXXX`. Unfortunately, the script contained some mistakes and apart from these replacements the Community bot also broke a few things. (Such as markup used in posts, & appearing in MathJax code, removing `[tag:tag-name]` wherever it is used, probably more....)

This was discussed on meta.stackexchange and SE developers are aware of it.
According to [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1993369#1993369) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown/230313#230313), there is a plan of rollback these changes soon. (Which will result in bumping lots of posts again, but the problem has to be corrected somehow.)

Comment: According to a comment by Oded on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown what was broken should be fixed and the posts got edited another time (and it seems without a second bump, though *now* it'd been almost irrelevant...)

Comment: That last paragraph makes me wonder if it is possible for a Community edit to make a post CW? Or do those somehow not count for that purpose?

Comment: @tomasz AFAIK the rule, that a post is automatically made CW after some number of edits, [has been recently canceled](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).